# Logging with Azure functions ~2.0

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I am trying to integrate `Microsoft.Logging.Extension` with Azure Functions ~2.

Logs below **LogLevel=Error** are not displayed in the Azure Log Stream or Kudu. The logs do appear in the console when running locally.

I create the factory as follows:

```
LoggerFactory factory = new LoggerFactory();
factory
    .AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics()
    .AddConsole();
```

Then I try to use the loggers as follows:

```
factory.CreateLogger<TestClass>().LogInformation("This is a test information message.");
```

My problem is: The logs won't show on Kudu/Azure Log Stream unless the level is **Error**

My `host.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "singleton": {
    "listenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15"
  },
  "logging": {
    "console": {
      "isEnabled": "true"
    },
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What if you don't use the logger factory, and just log with ILogger that is injected into your method?

Comment: The project I am working on is designed with classes other than the function's one. there should be a better solution than passing the logger instance that is injected to the function class to the rest of the project

Comment: The solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833645/azure-function-not-logging-to-application-insights) worked for me.