# logs not appearing in Application Insights for Azure Functions v4 with .NET 8

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I have functions being called, and I do logging as such:

```
_logger.LogInformation(...);
```

These **do show** in the live **Log Stream** on the portal.
However, when querying the logs in **Application Insights** (*traces*), they do **not show**. whereas all sorts of other info is available, such as

```
Executed 'Functions.<MyFunctionName>' (Succeeded, Id=a23d6397-3a9f-4663-8f26-1b2693a362d5, Duration=14523ms)
```

In my hosts.json file I have:

```
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
     ...
```

I also used the **telemetryClient**, and those items **do appear** (*customEvents*) in the logs. However, as I said, **the items from ILogger do not appear.**

| tech | In App Insights | In Live Log Stream |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ILogger<> | NO | YES |
| TelemetryClient | YES | NO |

This is happening with .NET 8 -- I did not have this issue using earlier .NET core versions; items logged via ILogger<> were showing up as expected in the traces table of Application Insights.

Any thoughts?

Additional info...
[ILogger info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#ilogger-logs)

This says that the config must look something like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Yet, the schema [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#sample-hostjson-file) contradicts that!

And even when I change my config to this, I cannot get anything lower than warnings to appear in Application Insights.

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77896586 Need to remove default rules

Comment: @PratikPandya Thank You! I will give it a try. It's really unfortunate that Microsoft requires so many odd, unintuitive, and obscure configurations, etc. to make some things work as you would expect them to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#start-up-and-configuration).

A filter, which is, unfortunately and bizarrely, automatically added, must be explicitly removed. Here's an example:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        s.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        s.AddSingleton<IHttpResponderService, DefaultHttpResponderService>();
        s.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            // The Application Insights SDK adds a default logging filter that instructs ILogger to capture only Warning and more severe logs. Application Insights requires an explicit override.
            // Log levels can also be configured using appsettings.json. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#ilogger-logs
            LoggerFilterRule toRemove = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

            if (toRemove is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(toRemove);
            }
        });
    })
    .Build();
```

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77565541/logs-not-appearing-in-application-insights-for-azure-functions-v4-with-net-8#comment137360516_77565541) comment and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77896586) answer.

Comment: If I follow this link I can see it mentions appsetting.json which is exactly what I use in my Azure Function with Options Pattern. Does it mean I can simply add this json to my appsettings.json file: {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: So writting this into host.json {
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Warning",
      "Function.MyFunction1": "Information",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace",
      "Host.Results": "Information"
    }
  }
} will not help? We cannot do this without the code change in Program.cs?

Comment: @OliverNilsen If you want items lower than warnings to appear, then you must follow the answer given, unfortunately.

Comment: How does the scale or range go? What is lowest and highest? Microsoft made this so complicated.

Comment: Upvoted. It does require to make this code change in Program.cs in order to show ILogger messages posted with LogInformation method.

Comment: I am confused by this statement from MS: "The Functions host and the isolated process worker have separate configuration for log levels, etc. Any Application Insights configuration in host.json will not affect the logging from the worker, and similarly, configuration made in your worker code will not impact logging from the host. You need to apply changes in both places if your scenario requires customization at both layers." Does it mean, I still need to modify the default host.json file and add LogLevel configuraiton there as well?

Answer (score 0):

I have created an Azure Function with an HTTP trigger and a runtime stack for .NET. I have set the Instrumentation Key to get logs in Application Insights.

**.csproject file:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Function code:**

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public class HttpTrigger1
    {
        private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

        public HttpTrigger1(TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration)
        {
            _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
        }

        [Function("HttpTrigger1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
                                    FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("HttpTrigger1");

            logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            _telemetryClient.TrackTrace("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.", Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel.Information);

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
 .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();

                services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights();

            // Set the minimum logging level to Information
            loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**host.json:**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "logginglevel":"Information",
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
        
    }
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "5ca2002e-c63e-4f48-857b-9042f6f436d2",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

[image]

I am able to get the logs in application insights. check below:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

After deployed to azure able to run successfully in azure also and getting logs in application insights.

[image]

Comment: Since you added your instrument key to local settings, I assume you are running locally. Do you get logs when it is running in Azure?

Comment: @Donny Kwitty   yes, when I ran function in azure also getting logs.  I have added the function running status in azure portal.

Comment: I think it is displaying your telemetry info rather than your log -- You have identical messages in your code. Please change the log and trace messages so that you can distinguish between them. LogInformation("this is logInformation") ... TrackTrace("this is trackTrace")

Comment: I tried as per you told. check these 
 [1](https://i.imgur.com/iZDyeI4.png) , [2](https://i.imgur.com/liKEBfC.png).

Comment: Pavan, image 1 in your comment is a track trace. Show me--from the logs--the log information... i.e. show me a query of the traces table that has both your trace and log in it. Thanks for your help!!